# I'm getting this Docusign Error CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: docusignapi

One of my colleagues have originally posted this question at Salesforce StackExchange but we were also advised to post it here since there might be more devs familiar here on DocuSign.

We're creating a Salesforce app that sends a PDF file to DocuSign for signing. However, when DocuSign returns the PDF, it gives us an error.

We've configured the DocuSign sandbox to return the document back to Salesforce using the information in this link: https://support.docusign.com/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-Adding-Completed-Documents-to-the-Notes-and-Attachments-New

Here is the error we get in the Docusign logs when it tries to return the document back to Salesforce:

> SFIntegration unable to add attachment to SF ID: 8001X000000TvWdQAK,
>   SF Table: Contract, Error: Unable for insert (ShareType=I)
>   ContentDocumentLink for Test_Completed.Error:ErrorCode =
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, fields = .Unable to insert
>   (ShareType=V) ContentDocumentLink for Test_Completed.Error:ErrorCode =
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, fields =

Can anyone help us what is the error all about? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. I changed the version to 39 using 'Reconfigure Login' link for the connection and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a salesforce trigger? it's probably failing and then trying to roll back the changes. 
Also, check if you have "Use Content Files" checked and what version of the API you're using. If you are using V2.1 with this checkbox - you may be getting this error.

(Later Edit):
You Must install Connect for Salesforce with 39 selected. If you had 21 selected and later change to 39 - that won't work, must have it from the beginning.